# Can't get the COUNT of DAYNAME

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) jumlah FROM pasien WHERE DAYNAME(created_at) = 'Tuesday'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
var_dump($result); var_dump($row);
```

Above is my code. I tried this on phpmyadmin and it return 1. When i run this on php returns NULL.

[image: Here when I run it on phpmyadmin]

[image: Here when i run on the web]

Edit :
I use `mysqli_error` to see what's wrong with it and the result :

[image: The error now with mysqli_error]

Comment: This code should never return `NULL`.  If no rows match in the table, then it would return `0`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` does actually return null if there are no rows.

Comment: @BadHorsie see my edit picture.

Comment: The brackets in your query string are probably breaking it. Check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) along each step of the way to make sure it's working.

Comment: @aynber no sorry that was my edit. New to stackoverflow. See the edit now

Comment: Result appears to be false, so you may still want to check for mysqli errors

Comment: @BadHorsie . . . That doesn't matter.  An aggregation query with no `group by` (or `having`) *always* returns one row.

Comment: Interesting that PHPMyAdmin can see created_at, but not PHP. Are they accessing the exact same database and table?

Comment: @aynber AHHHHH THANKYOU! they did NOT access the same database! My bad.